# Bash script - Postgres COPY to table from CSV returning COPY 0

Tags: postgresql, bash, csv, copy

I have created a bash script to copy CSV data into a Postgres table.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    
    PSQL=/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/psql
    
    DB_USER=user
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_NAME=dbname
    export PGPASSWORD="password"
    
    file_path="/Users/user/test.csv"
    
    echo "copy started .."
    
    result=$($PSQL -X -U $DB_USER -h $DB_HOST -P t -P format=unaligned -c "\\COPY table_name FROM '$file_path' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER" $DB_NAME)
    
    echo "copy completed : $result"
```

This always returns COPY 0 and no records are added.

Tried running the copy command on terminal as well but same result.

I am missing something here?

Comment: It seems like the most obvious explanation is that /Users/user/test.csv has 0 or 1 row in it.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes for your reply. I can confirm the CSV has few records in it.